# Running keychain as different user

Tags: linux, ssh

In order to improve security a bit, I'd like to run the `keychain` agent as a different user. This shall prevent users who hijack my system from gaining the actual private key, while maintaining the ability to use it to authenticate `ssh` and `scp` connections.

What have I tried?

I created a user called `agent` who should store the private key and run the ssh-agent process. I created a script file to set up the right permissions for the socket:

```
#!/bin/sh
export EVAL=$(keychain --eval -q)
eval $EVAL
chmod 770 $(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK) $(dirname $GPG_AGENT_INFO)
chmod 660 $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $(echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO | sed 's/:.*//')
echo $EVAL
```

And call that one in my `.bashrc`, eval'ing it.

But when I now connect to a server via `ssh`, I get

```
$ ssh server
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keychain` seems to use either an already running `ssh-agent` or `gpg-agent`, and start one if needed.

`ssh-agent` checks if the user id of the running process matches the id of the user connecting through the unix domain socket (with the exception of root). If you run the agent in debug mode you'll see the corresponding error message. In this case the socket is immediately closed, so you'll get the error message you mention above - you're probably using `ssh-agent` on your system. That means what you try to do won't be possible using `ssh-agent` (unless you don't modify it).

It should work if you use `gpg-agent` with the `--enable-ssh-support` option as replacement for `ssh-agent`, but you should be aware that this setup doesn't really increase security. With the permissions you're trying to set, it would allow every user that has access rights to the socket the to authenticate as you using the added key once it has been unlocked, so it's actually less secure.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is less secure. Actually, it is only every user on the user group (so maybe only him and the dummy user), but I as well don't see the benefit...

Comment: @glglgl: I'm the only user in that group, for your given reasons. My setup does increase security a little IMO, because a potential attacker couldn't take the (still encrypted) keys.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reason why that ssh-agent doesn't like my other user to connect. :)